# Web crawler breaks when website is changed

Tags: java, jsoup, web-crawler

I have created a web crawler according to [this example](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/12/how-to-make-a-web-crawler-using-java/).

This is working OK, but if I replace

```
processPage("http://www.mit.edu");
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.mit.edu/").get();
```

with

```
processPage("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.stackoverflow.com/").get();
```

or the same text, but for other sites, then this returns only the text "conn built".

Why is this not working for other sites?

Answer (score 0):

I did not try the code but my guess is on accessing "http://www.stackoverflow.com" it returns `HTTP Response code-301 or 302`. That means it redirects to different page. My guess is the library you are using does not handle the 301/302 response codes well.

So try this url instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions. It should work if my assumption is correct.